# AWS S3 Presigned URL limited to one object upload per URL - How to upload multiple images

Tags: design, aws

I have a AWS Lambda function that a user makes a `GET request` to and it returns presigned URL. The user then uploads an image by making a PUT request to that URL. Since AWS S3 `PUT requests` limits object uploads to only one per URL,

How would I send multiple images? Am I supposed to use a loop on the current number of images e.g:

Say the user wants to upload 5 images.

```
for(...5 images...){
   Make GET request to generate URL
   In the callback method, 
   Make a PUT request to the generated URL to upload image
}
```

I am not sure if the service is intended to be used this way. And also this causes another issue, say what if I want all the images to be uploaded and saved into my DB, or none to be saved. Because in the `PUT request's` post process Lambda function, I want to save that S3 image URL into my database, how do I ensure all the images are uploaded and not only 3/5 of them, if the network fails?

Comment: You can zip all the images you need as a zip file and try unzip on your put request's post process lambda function. It will increase the processing time. But achieves all the use case you wanted.

Comment: Yes, probably like that.